# Tracing Memory Leaks in Python using Dowser

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I am running some tests nightly on a VM with a centos operating system. Recently the tests have been taking up all the memory available and nearly all the swap memory on the machine, I assigned the VM twice as much memory and it's still happening, which results in the physical host machine of the VM dying. These tests were previously running without needing half as much memory so I need to use some form of **python memory analyzer** to investigate what is going on.

I've looked at **Pysizer** and **Heapy** -- but after research **Dowser** seems to be the one I'm after as it requires zero changes to code.

So far from the documentation and googling I've got this code in it's own class:

```
import cherrypy
import dowser

class MemoryAnalyzer:

def memoryCheck(self):
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port':8080})
    cherrypy.tree.mount(dowser.Root())
    cherrypy.engine.start()
```

I was hoping this would bring up the web interface shown in the documentation to track all instance of python running on the host, which doesn't work. I was confused by the documentation:

```
   'python dowser __init__.py'.
```

Is it possible to just run this? I get the error :

```
  /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__.py' in 'dowser'
```

Can dowser run independently from my test suite on the VM? Or will I have to implement this above code into my main class to run my tests to trace instances of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get dowser to work using this blog http://www.aminus.org/blogs/index.php/2008/06/11/tracking-memory-leaks-with-dowser?blog=2 and changing the port to 8088 instead of 8080(which wasn't in use on the machine but still doesn't work!)

Answer (score 3):

Dowser is meant to be run as part of your application. Therefore, wherever you initialize the application, add the lines

```
import dowser
cherrypy.tree.mount(dowser.Root(), '/dowser')
```

Then you can browse to `http://localhost:8080/dowser` to view the dowser interface.

Note that the invocation you quoted from the documentation is for testing dowser. The correct invocation for that is `python dowser/__init__.py`.